# How to display a php variable from every post in a WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I have a custom post type, and in each post I have a variable called `$grandtotal`. The value of `$grandtotal` is the result of a calculation from data entered on a frontend form on the post.

In my template for posts, I have this:

```
<?php echo '<h5>Grand Total: '. $grandtotal . '</h5>' ?>
```

Which outputs this, for example:

**Grand Total: 543**

Now, on another page, I need to run a loop of all posts and display each post's `$grandtotal` value. Not all their content -- just the post title with the `$grandtotal`.

How can I pull this variable? Can I store the `$grandtotal` into the database somehow so I can pull it into the loop? I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE with answer**
In case someone needs it, here is the final code I used based on the correct answer below.

```
  <?php if( $grandtotal ) {
        add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'grandtotal', $grandtotal, true ) or
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'grandtotal', $grandtotal );

      }; ?>
```

and then in the loop, I called it with this:

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'grandtotal', true ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes........

```
update_post_meta($postid, meta_key, value); 
e.g. update_post_meta(232,"_grandtotal", 200);
```

and to pull

```
$value= get_post_meta(232,"_grandtotal");
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you! Do you have to specify a post ID? I checked the codex and it looks like you do. I want to do this for unlimited number of posts, so I'd rather it just be the "current post ID", as opposed to having to specify it each time. Is that possible?

Comment: Or, wait... I can use $post_id and that should give the current ID... I think? I'll try that.

Comment: Yes. This worked. I used get_the_ID() instead of a specific ID. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your variable values as Custom Post Meta, and you can get the value on your loop using [get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)